# Analyzing TCP Traffic

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, wireshark, ns-3

I just ran a simulation for multipath tcp protocol sending 100,000 bytes from client to server in the network simulator 3. I got the trace file (pcap) and analyzed it in Wire Shark. The [flow graph](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7UgPdr2ZHOPSDRya1VtV0REaWc/view?usp=sharing) is very weird. How can ACKs be sent and received on both sides ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can ACKs be sent and received on both sides ?

Because that's how TCP works.  [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) says:

```
Acknowledgment Number:  32 bits

  If the ACK control bit is set this field contains the value of the
  next sequence number the sender of the segment is expecting to
  receive.  Once a connection is established this is always sent.
```

so, once the connection is established, *every single packet in the connection has the ACK bit set*.